# aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError when using proxy (clash) when doownloading CMIP6 data through pangeo

Tags: python, proxy, ssl-certificate, client, zarr

## 1. Environment

- Linux (#44~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon May 22 13:39:36 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)
- Anaconda (23.1.0)
- running a proxy (clash)
- conda environment created by [python_pangeo_cmip6](https://github.com/dr-ko/python_pangeo_cmip6)

## 2. Logs/tracks

```
$ python get_cmip6.py inputIPSL_hist.json                                  (pg_cimpr) 
using metadta from https://storage.googleapis.com/cmip6/cmip6-zarr-consolidated-stores.csv
Trying to download: 
table_id == 'Amon' & variable_id == 'hfls' & experiment_id == 'historical' & source_id == 'IPSL-CM6A-LR' & member_id == 'r1i1p1f1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1081, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1111, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 856, in _read_ready__data_received
    data = self._sock.recv(self.max_size)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/hgfs/F/Data/Original/CMIP6/LFMIP-pdLC/python_pangeo_cmip6/get_cmip6.py", line 93, in <module>
    ds = xr.open_zarr(mapper, consolidated=True)
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/backends/zarr.py", line 675, in open_zarr
    ds = open_dataset(
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 572, in open_dataset
    store = opener(filename_or_obj, **extra_kwargs, **backend_kwargs)
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/backends/zarr.py", line 294, in open_group
    zarr_group = zarr.open_consolidated(store, **open_kwargs)
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zarr/convenience.py", line 1178, in open_consolidated
    meta_store = ConsolidatedMetadataStore(store, metadata_key=metadata_key)
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zarr/storage.py", line 2680, in __init__
    meta = json_loads(store[metadata_key])
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fsspec/mapping.py", line 132, in __getitem__
    result = self.fs.cat(k)
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py", line 241, in cat
    raise ex
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py", line 826, in _cat_file
    headers, out = await self._call("GET", u2)
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py", line 487, in _call
    async with self.session.request(
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/home/cool70/anaconda3/envs/pg_cimpr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 975, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host www.googleapis.com:443 ssl:default [Connection reset by peer]
```

---

The problem is related to the proxy I'm running, it failed to reach google api.
Anyone in China has the solution?

I can use other python packages to download CMIP6 data like `acccmip6`, or through official CMIP6 website. But this repository can regrid the nc files and choose the wanted time period while downloading data, so there would be less data pre-processing.